# Is there a difference between Object.list = {} and list = {}?

Tags: javascript, list, object

I really wonder if there is a difference other than making the code more structured between Object.list = {} and list = {}?

Example:

```
    var Player = function(){
    }
    Player.list = {};
    var list = {};
```

Comment: One adding it as propert to the Player object (function) and the other one declaring it as a standalone variable

Comment: Those 2 pieces of code are not equivalent.

Comment: I'm more curious on why you would think they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable as below:

```
var list = {};
```

the variable is created on the `window` global object and it is equivalent to following code:

```
window.list = {};
```

The problem with it is there could be couple JavaScript files on the page that contain the same variable defined in two or more places, which creates name clashing issue. To avoid that scenario you can declare your own name space and define a new variable there

```
var Player = function(){
}
Player.list = {};
```

Comment: It is worth noting a variable is only global if declared out of the scope of a function. That is why wrapping code blocks in IIFE's was common before modules came along.

Answer (score 1):

`Player.list` defines `list` **within** the `Player` function. As such, it only has scope within that function, and cannot be used outside of the function (without explicitly stating that it's a global). Conversely, `var list` allows you to use `list` globally by default.